# How to compile OCaml and C/C++ code that depend on each other

Tags: c++, c, ocaml

I'm having problems defining the signature of a C void function that accepts an `uint64_t` and a `char*`. I tried `int64 -> string -> _`.

I also don't know how to compile my C++ file (with C interface) together

**events.ml**

```
open Lwt.Infix

external call: int64 -> string -> _ = "function_pointer_caller"

let begin_event pointer = 
    Lwt_unix.sleep 5.0 >>= fun () ->
        call pointer "message"

let () = Callback.register "begin_event" begin_event
```

**interface.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <caml/mlvalues.h>
#include <caml/callback.h>
#include <caml/alloc.h>
#include <caml/bigarray.h>

extern void register_function_callback();

void print_from_event(char* message) {
    printf("OCaml event: %s\n", message);
}

void function_pointer_caller(uint64_t pointer, char* message)
{
    void (*f)(char *);
    f = pointer;
}

void register_function_callback() {
    static const value *begin_event_closure = NULL;
    if (begin_event_closure == NULL)
    {
        begin_event_closure = caml_named_value("begin_event");
        if (begin_event_closure == NULL)
        {
            printf("couldn't find OCaml function\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    uint64_t pointer = (uint64_t) &function_pointer_caller;
    caml_callback(*begin_event_closure, (int64_t) &pointer);
}
```

**main.cc**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <caml/callback.h>

extern "C" void register_function_callback();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  caml_startup(argv);
  register_function_callback();
  while (true)
  {
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I think there's no way to compile a .cc together with a .ml, because a .cc does not necessairly have a C interface. Maybe it's possible to compile the .ml to a .so object and link it to the .cc with the C interface?

Anyways, I did change `interface.cc` to `interface.c` and added `interface.c` to the `ocamlopt` command:

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -o s -linkpkg -package lwt.unix -thread event_emitter.ml interface.c

g++ -o event_emitter_program -I $(ocamlopt -where) \
    s.o interface.o main.cc event_emitter.o $(ocamlopt -where)/libasmrun.a -ldl
```

The first command compiles ok, but g++ gives

```
event_emitter.o: In function `camlEvent_emitter__begin_event_90':
:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `camlLwt_unix__sleep_695'
:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `camlLwt__bind_1276'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Notice that I plug the `interface.o` from the previous command (`ocamlopt`) and link in g++, because `ocamlopt` actually passes C files to a C compiler.

I don't know why it complains about `Lwt_unix` things, since I already compiled with them in `ocamlopt`.

Comment: Try `extern "C"`

Comment: @KamilCuk but there's still the need to specify which .cc file will be compiled together with the .ml, otherwise it will always result to "undefined reference"

Comment: link with ocaml when buiilding. `I already compiled with them in ocamlopt` don't `$(ocamlopt -where)/libasmrun.a` do `-lasmrun`. and `-lunix`

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry I didn't understand. `$(ocamlopt -where)/libasmrun.a` is the same as  `-lasmrun` isn't it? And `-lunix` gives `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunix`

Comment: : / Navigate to `ocmlopt -where` and list symbols in libraries  and find the missing symbols. Something along `for i in $(ocamlopt -where)/*.so; do nm -gD "$i" | grep camlLwt_unix__sleep_695 && echo $i; done`.  `isn't it?` - I guess it's the same if linker finds the same library.  You didn't `-L$(ocamlopt -where)`. I feel like `-l` is more "correct" - it let's ocaml choose if it wants static or shared library.

Comment: @KamilCuk the for does not give any results. However I was able to do like this: `g++ -o event_emitter_program -I $(ocamlopt -where) 
    s.o interface.o main.cc -L$(ocamlc -where) -lunix -lasmrun -ldl`. There's no unefined references to `unix_` things anymore but obviously it is still missing the `lwt_unix` things and other OCaml functions: https://pastebin.com/ukyx9yE0

Comment: Try changing `-lunix -lasmrun`  to `-lasmrun -lunix` or specifying it twice.

Comment: @KamilCuk it worked, now no errors on unix things anymore, only OCaml things like `caml_mutex_new`. Do you have any ideas? https://pastebin.com/9W2gNnNz

Comment: This link shows how to call ocaml callbacks from c: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#s%3Ac-callback

Answer (score 3):

The `ocamlopt` utility is doing a bit more than just linking the specified compilation units and libraries, it also embeds the architecture startup code, which is not included in the `asmrun` library. It is possible to obtain this code using the `-output-obj`, but I find it a little bit error-prone and hard to maintain as it is not really composable<sup>1</sup>.

So, it is better to rely on ocamlopt to build the final binary, which will consist of modules written in different languages. Each unit will be built with the appropriate to the language, in which it is written, tool. Let's build the `events.ml` compilation unit:

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -c -package lwt.unix events.ml
```

Now, let's build the interface (we can use `cc` here, but using ocamlopt will save us a bit of hassle of providing the location of the includes)

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -c interface.c
```

Now, let's build the C++ part (but first fix it and use `caml_main` instead of `caml_startup` since we want the native runtime).

```
g++ -c main.cc -o main.o -I `ocamlc -where`
```

Now, when we have all units we're ready for the final linking command:

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt events.cmx interface.o main.o -package lwt.unix -package lwt -thread -linkpkg -o emitter
```

Et voila, we can run our program with `./emitter`.

---

<sup>1)</sup> using this option for more than one compilation unit may easily lead to symbol conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You should be more careful with “warning” messages and not rely on things that bind the building process to your configuration. Avoid usage of root console please!

```
[WARNING] Running as root is not recommended
```

In the root environment path to libraries can be complicated.

According to your pastebin I see that linker is unable to locate the lwt_unix_stubs library. And don't mix '.a' and '.so' libraries please (`/root/.opam/4.10.0/lib/lwt/unix/liblwt_unix_stubs.a /root/.opam/4.10.0/lib/stublibs/dlllwt_unix_stubs.so`)! '.a' is for static build while '.so' is for dynamic.

Example of build that works for me (Ubuntu Linux, ocaml 4.05.0):

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -output-obj -dstartup -linkpkg -package lwt.unix -thread -o s.o event_emitter.ml
g++ -o event_emitter_program -I`ocamlfind c -where` -I $(ocamlopt -where) s.o interface.o main.cc -L `ocamlc -where` -L`ocamlfind query lwt.unix` -L`ocamlfind query threads` -lasmrun -llwt_unix_stubs -lunix -lbigarray -lcamlstr -lthreadsnat -lpthread -ldl
```

Usage of `$(ocamlopt -where)/libasmrun.a` is bad idea. It's more pedantic way to use -lasmrun and -L for path to libraries.

If you have problems with some undefined symbols, it's best to use **readelf** to find out which library is missing.

Comment: `opam env` is the command in opam 2.0. You're still using opam 1.x which is deprecated and is no longer supported and no packages are anymore released for opam 1.x

Comment: Thanks. It's root because it's on a docker environment. Gonna fix that later.